# How to use Airbnb Caravel Time Filter

Tags: apache-superset

Recently, I use Caravel to do Log Analytics Dashboard, and I think Caravel Time filter is not good to use, for example:

- I can't display all data without Time filter
- Time filter is too rough, so I can't get data within two datetime

Is any way can resolve these problem?  Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the default port to connect to Caravel UI ? Please help.
I have setup Caravel on my mac, install is complete and I have done the example load step as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

In Time Filter, you can just type 1 day, 2 day or a date string in Since and Until field